# Call to api slow with ajax

Tags: ajax, api, guzzle

I am making an api call from a guzzle client in the following manner :

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();  
$call = API_URL.$resource.'?start='.$start.'&length='.$length.'&order_by='.$order_by.'&order_dir='.$order_dir.'&'.$this->input->server('QUERY_STRING');         
$res = $client->request('GET', $call, [
            'headers' => [
                'X-API-KEY'      => [API_KEY]
            ]
        ]);
```

If I call the api synchronously, no problem the call is fast. 
But if I call the api with ajax it takes up to 20s to perform the $client->request. The strangest thing is if I submit the request again (with ajax) it works fine. It only happens for the first call.
It's almost like some caching process is taking place somewhere..but where ? It's not a database issue as the delay never occurs synchronously. (btw I also tried with curl rather than guzzle, same issue).

Comment: What's happening on the server side that you're making the request to? Do you have access to that code base?

Comment: Yes I wrote the api (codeigniter api rest). How could it be the problem if it’s absolutely fine synchronously ?

Comment: Try adding a `'Connection' => 'close'` header to the request and see if that resolves it.